# How to change Django abstract model to a real model?

Tags: django, django-models

Currently I have an abstract base model:

```
class Work(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(Person, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True) 

    class Meta:
       abstract = True
```

From which two other model inherits from:

```
class WorkMusic(MPTTModel, Work):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    tonality = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    tempo = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

class WorkVisual(Work):
    material = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    material_original = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

I realize now that it would be nice to have a table all both Musical and Visual Work together. I should have NOT made my Work model abstract. Is there a way to convert the Work model into not an abstract model?

I tried removing:

```
class Meta:
   abstract = True
```

and loading my WorkMusic fixture (with only the fields in the Work model), hoping it would also create regular inheritance instances in the Work model. But that gave me unique key conflicts. Any other solutions to this issue?

Comment: Are you dependent on your database? Or are you still developing and ready to delete all migrations and databases?

Comment: Still developing. However, these models are dependent on other models. So resetting the 'pk's will have effects on other tables.

Comment: You did not provide the entire code for the models, right? Right now I don't see why there would be a unique key conflict. It is correct to remove `Meta`class. Read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) about your options to subclass. Read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) about what you are trying to do. Read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#inheritance-and-reverse-relations) about why errors might occur for you. With more code I can help more.

Comment: @Tarquinius Thanks for the help. It's a little hard to describe the table setup. I basically have many music-specific tables that are linked to WorkMusic. WorkVisual has fewer but some table link to it. When I do a dumpdata, each entry obviously right now has a unique 'pk'. From your link to the Django documentation, it seems like I can dumpdata with natural keys? So the order of operation might be this? 1. dump current DB data with no pk. 2. Update Meta to be abstract-False, 3. load data back into the new DB? This should create the appropriate entries in Work?